Question on the sftp remote linux path in a C# program
I am trying to use SSH.NET to connect a linux server with SFTP connection to download file to a window directory.
Here is my code
string hostname = "1.1.1.1";
            string username = "test";
            string password = "test";
            string localFilePath = @"C:\test\";
            string NasFolderPath = “I have no idea about this path”;
            string remoteDestinationPath = "";

            LogWriter.LogWrite("Dest: "+ localFilePath + ", Source: " +NasFolderPath);

            try
            {
                using (var client = new SshClient(hostname, 22, username, password))
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    LogWriter.LogWrite("connectClient");

                    var sftp = new SftpClient(client.ConnectionInfo);
                    sftp.Connect();
                    LogWriter.LogWrite("ConnectSFTP");

                    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(NasFolderPath);
                    LogWriter.LogWrite("ConnectFolder" + files);
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        LogWriter.LogWrite(file.ToString());
                        if (!file.IsDirectory)
                        {
                            LogWriter.LogWrite("HaveDirectory");
                            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(localFilePath, file.Name)))
                            {
                                LogWriter.LogWrite("TryToCopyFile");
                                sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                                LogWriter.LogWrite("File downloaded and moved successfully.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sftp.Disconnect();

                    // Download the file


                    ////Upload the file
                    //using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("localFilePath"))
                    //{
                    //    client.UploadFile(fileStream, "remoteDestinationPath", true);
                    //}

                    ////Optionally, delete the source file
                    //client.DeleteFile("remoteFilePath");

                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogWriter.LogWrite($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

The path to directory in the linux server is “volume1/TestFile”
I have tried to use
“sftp://test@1.1.1.1/volume1/TestFile”
“sftp://test@1.1.1.1/volume1/TestFile/”
“1.1.1.1/volume1/TestFile”
“1.1.1.1/volume1/TestFile/”
“sftp://test@1.1.1.1/TestFile”
“sftp://test@1.1.1.1/TestFile/”
“1.1.1.1/TestFile”
“1.1.1.1/TestFile/”
“\1.1.1.1\TestFile\”
But seems all of this return with an error message “no such file”
What is the correct path for NasFolderPath?
or is there any other error of my code?

Shouldn't it be string NasFolderPath = @"volume1/TestFile"? What do yo get from ListDirectories? Also why are you using SshClient and SftpClient that's just going to open two separate connections

@Charlieface There are severals files in the Testfile and it will be updated frequently, therefore I need a ListDirectories to get the name of the files inside. So I can only use SFTPclient and deleted the SshClient?

Yes. So what is the exact error message with stack trace, and what value are you using for NasFolderPath? What do you get if you browse down from the root /

@Charlieface Thank you for your help. you give me the answer. String NasFolderPath = @“/TestFile”
and only need to use SftpClient only. Thank you

string NasFolderPath = @"volume1/TestFile"
only need to use SftpClient only
